# What is the difference between accuracy and precision?

Tags: validation, accuracy, precision

I read the [material](https://www.ncsu.edu/labwrite/Experimental%20Design/accuracyprecision.htm) on the difference betweeen accuracy and precision, but it makes me feel confused. Can I define accuracy as:
\begin{equation}
accuracy=\frac{TruePositive+TrueNegative}{TruePositive+TrueNegative+FalsePositive+FlaseNegative}
\end{equation}

So in machine learning, what is the difference between accuracy and precision?

Comment: [This picture](https://www.google.com/#q=accuracy+precision+bullseye) is a good way to internalize the difference. (In machine learning, accuracy vs. precision is actually analogous to bias vs. variance, if you are familiar with that.)

Comment: @GeoMatt22, thank you, can I define accuracy as :\begin{equation}
accuracy=\frac{TruePositive+TrueNegative}{TruePositive+TrueNegative+FalsePositive+FlaseNegative}
\end{equation}

Comment: Aaah, now I see your confusion. "Accuracy" and "precision" are general terms throughout science (and have the sense indicated by the bullseye diagrams I linked to before). However in the *particular* context of [Binary Classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_of_binary_classifiers) these terms have very specific definitions. The chart at that Wikipedia page gives these. (Note that this context is more specialized than just "machine learning".)

Comment: Just for reference, I made my comments into an answer. (We have far too many "unanswered questions" already that are answered in the comments!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Just for reference, I am posting my comments as an answer. Note that the first version of the question did not include the formula.)

["Accuracy" and "precision"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) are general terms throughout science. A good way to internalize the difference are the common "[bullseye diagrams](https://www.google.com/#q=accuracy+precision+bullseye)". In machine learning/statistics as a whole, accuracy vs. precision is analogous to [bias vs. variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff).

However in the *particular* context of [Binary Classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_of_binary_classifiers)* these terms have very specific definitions. The chart at that Wikipedia page gives these, which are
$$\mathrm{Accuracy}=\frac{\mathrm{True}}{\mathrm{Total}} \text{ , } 
\mathrm{Precision}=\frac{\mathrm{True\;Positive}}{\mathrm{All\;Positive}}
$$
i.e. the fraction of cases that are correctly classified vs. the fraction of positives that are true.

(*Note that this context is much more specialized than simply "machine learning".)